# PHP get the year from the variable

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I usually mess this up, but I am trying to get a year from a variable `$date = 2011-01-01` I am trying to get `2011` from the variable...I tried this but it didnt echo anything out...

```
date(strtotime("Y"), strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$year = date('Y', strtotime('2011-01-01'));
```

Or, if you don't want to convert to date, and trust your input format:

```
$year = explode('-', '2011-01-01')[0];
```

The above requires PHP 5.4, on older versions you need two lines:

```
$arr = explode('-', '2011-01-01');
$year = $arr[0];
```

Or yet, this slightly faster alternative suggested by tigrang:

```
$year = substr($date, 0, 4);
```

Or, an even faster way, as salathe suggested:

```
$year = (int) $date;
```

(everything after the first dash will be ignored, so `$year` will contain an integer with the year part of the date (unlike the other options, where `$year` would be a string).

Comment: or `$year = substr($date, 0, 4);` being sliiiightly faster ;)

Comment: or `$year = (int) $date;` being *waaaaaaaay* faster (for tiny values of *way*)

Comment: Post marked community wiki, anyone feel free to contribute other option by editing directly.

Comment: My answer has a couple more *super-useful* alternatives, feel free to steal them.

Answer (score 3):

`date('Y', strtotime($date))` should do

First arg is the format, second is timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

You can explode the date into a list and call each date item individually.

```
$date = '2012-01-01';
list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $date);

echo $year; // echoes 2012
```

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest using PHP's [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) as an alternative:

```
$date = '2011-01-01'; 
$dateTime = new DateTime($date);

echo $dateTime->format('Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` is all well and good, but lets go old school.

```
sscanf($date, '%d', $year);
// or
$year = strtok($date, '-');
// or
$year = substr($date, 0, 4);
// or
$year = (int) $date;
```

**or**, putting the sensible hat back on, you could use `DateTime` or correctly use `date()`.

```
$datetime = new DateTime($date);
$year = $datetime->format('Y');
// or
$year = date('Y', strtotime($date));
```